# Discord のメッセージを保存(？)したい

Tags: python, discord

discord.pyでボットを作っています。
送られてきたメッセージをリストに保存してあとから一覧を出せるようにしたいのですが保存されません。

調べ方がわからず、参考資料はありません。

全然わからないので教えていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

以下がコードです。

**main.py**

```
import nutslist as n
sys.path.append("パス")
---
中略
---
@client.event
async def on_message(m):
---
中略
---
    elif m.content.startswith("p"):
        un = m.content
        uname = un.split(' ')
        dicer = uname[1]
        n.nuts.append(dicer)
        (un, uname) = (None, None)
        await m.channel.send("done")
```

**nutslist.py**

```
nuts = []
```

Comment: 全部をまとめて1度にやろうとせずに、少しづつ実現していってはどうでしょう？ 取っ掛かりとしてこんな記事が参考になるかもしれません。[Discord.py make bot copy every message, including files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66094282/9014308), [How to copy all messages from the channel in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63068385/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます
少しずつやってみようと思います